# PGP key for Rails deployment tutorial

Tags: deployment, pgp

In [this portion of the tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-5-%E2%80%94-install-passenger) I'm using, I'm supposed to setup a PGP key.

Should I use the one they list, or is that just a placeholder? If so, how do I choose what key I want to use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to type that exact command.

The command fetches the PGP public key of the repository.  Then `apt-get` will use that public key to automatically verify the signature of all packages downloaded from that repository.